# DNN: how to un-disable browser back button?

Tags: dotnetnuke, back

I am helping out with a site built using DNN (DotNetNuke).  A certain set of pages are somehow blocking the browser's back button.  We don't want this behavior.  How do we re-enable it?  I suspect there's a setting somewhere that's gotten turned on accidentally, but I haven't been able to find any reference to that in the documentation.

Comment: By trial and error, I've determined that a SmartSheet iframe on these pages is somehow causing the back button to not work.  The html for it looks like:

`<iframe width="1110" height="1000" frameborder="0" src="https://app.smartsheet.com/b/publish?EQBCT=8b5795f0d5504484874b0114d0aefbd6"></iframe>`

Removing this from the page allows the browser's back button to work; putting it back blocks the back button from working.  So, the revised question is, how to include a SmartSheet iframe without messing up the back button?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of such a setting.  It might be in your theme (skin), possibly in some javascript.